# How do I limit AWS CloudFont so that it only serves requests from a single directory on my domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have gone through the process of creating a CloudFront distribution with the Origin Domain Name pointing to my main Rails application where assets (images, css, js, ect) are located at `/assets`.

However, by default, the CloudFront distribution is mirroring the entire domain (including dynamic pages).

How can I limit it to just the `/assets` sub-tree?

PS This is the article I am following:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-amazon-cloudfront-cdn

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the default cache behavior can't (afaik) be removed, this seems like a clever "serverless" solution:

- Create a bucket in S3. The name won't matter.  Don't put anything in it.
- Add a second origin to your CloudFront distribution, selecting the new bucket as the origin.
- Create a second cache behavior with path pattern `/assets/*` pointing to your original origin.
- Change the default cache behavior to use the new S3 origin (the unused, empty bucket).
- CloudFront will forward requests for `/assets/*` to your existing server, where they will be handled as now, but all other requests will be sent to the empty bucket, which has no content and no permissions, so the response will be `403 Forbidden`.
- Optionally, add an appropriate "robots.txt" file to that otherwise-empty bucket, and make it publicly readable, so CloudFront will serve it up to any crawlers that visit your CloudFront distribution, disallowing them from indexing, which should hopefully prompt them to remove any already-indexed results and not try to index the assets or any other paths they might have already learned by crawling the previously-exposed content at the "wrong" URL.

[image: The red line is origin (Rails) server]

Comment: That is ingenious! Ive just tested it out and it works great! Thank you